# connecting multiple tables in a database using keys in sql

Tags: sql

I have a table named **student** with columns *studentid*, *name*, *address*, *email*, *phone*.
Each student may have multiple email-id and multiple phone numbers. I want to record all emails and phone numbers too. So, I manipulates the **student** table columns by removing *email-id* column and *phone* column  And created another table **studentemail** with columns *emailserialnumber* , *email-id*. And one more table **studentphone** with columns *phoneserialnumber* , *phone*. student table consists of *studentid*, *name*, *address* columns. should I add anymore columns to student table to maintain relation with other tables. Now I have three tables. now how can I relate the tables using keys.  I mean like which column should I make primary key and foreign key so that three tables are connected.

Thank you

Comment: You need to show us the queries you tried to use. Read more about how ask question here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your `studentemail` and `studentphone` tables need to include a FK relationship with `student` - they need to contain a field for the `studentid`

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Only tag the question with the database you are really using.

Comment: It would be better if you screenshot your table design.

Comment: so in **studentemail** and **studentphone** tables  the studentid column should be marked as foreign key and studentid column in student table should be marked as primary key right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `studentemail` and `studentphone` tables simply need another column to reference the `student` table.  In your case, this would be the `studentid` column.

You can then bring the data together in a single query.  I should note that you might want a column that specifies *what* the email and phone numbers are -- home, mobile, work, and so on.

Comment: @DotNetbeginner . . . Yes, you can add multiple phone numbers and multiple phones.  You seem to be on the right track.